# Job Control: How to save output of background job in a variable

Tags: bash, background-process, command-substitution, parallelism

Using Bash in OSX.

My script has these 2 lines:

```
nfiles=$(rsync -auvh --stats --delete --progress --log-file="$SourceRoot/""CopyLog1.txt" "$SourceTx" "$Dest1Tx" | tee /dev/stderr | awk '/files transferred/{print $NF}') &
nfiles2=$(rsync -auvh --stats --delete --progress --log-file="$SourceRoot/""CopyLog2.txt" "$SourceTx" "$Dest2Tx" | tee /dev/stderr | awk '/files transferred/{print $NF}')
```

When I use the `&` after the first line (to run the two rsync commands in parallel), my later call to `$nfiles` returns nothing.

Code:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "'$nfiles' files transferred to MASTER," & return & "'$nfiles2' transferred to BACKUP," & return & "Log Files Created" with title "Copy Complete"'
```

Can't figure out what's going on.  I need the 2 rsyncs to run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your example will not work is because the background command is executed in a subshell environment, therefore the value of `$nfiles` will not be available (ie: in your sample code, it's lost).

One easy way around this problem would be to use a temporary file. In the generalized sample code below, I've replaced you `rsync` pipelines with simpler commands which `sleep` and echo an arbitrary number:

```
# use existing value of TMPDIR if exists, else set it to /tmp
: ${TMPDIR:=/tmp}

# ensure temporary file will be deleted on interrupt or error:
trap "rm -f $TMPDIR/nfiles.$$; exit 1" 1 2 3 15

# run the first command in background and save output to a temporary file:
(sleep 3; echo 1) > $TMPDIR/nfiles.$$ &

nfiles2=$(sleep 1; echo 2)

# wait for background command to complete:
wait

# save temporary file data in variables:
nfiles=$(cat $TMPDIR/nfiles.$$)

# remove the temp files on normal exit:
rm -f $TMPDIR/nfiles.$$

# $nfiles and $nfiles 2 should now contain the desired data
echo nfiles=$nfiles
echo nfiles2=$nfiles2
```

Comment: The way you create temporary files is insecure: a local user could use this to overwrite your own files. Use `mktemp` instead.

Comment: @Gilles Doh! I agree. I'll get to it tomorrow or feel free to edit.